# What do "cells" and "lifts" mean in the sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> Conventional sanitary landfills consist of **cells** and **lifts** with liners, drains, gas vents, leak detection systems with intermediate and final covers.

In the dictionary, **cell** means "the smallest basic unit of a plant or animal" or "a small room", and **lift** means "elevator". While, the literal meanings do not make sense.
As a non-native speaker, I often puzzle over the uncommon meaning of the word. Are there any methods to know the uncommon meanings of the words?

Comment: I would say in this case cell in this instance is synonymous with 'compartment'. I think the work 'lift' is a term specifically related to landfill so this is tricky.

Comment: *Are there any methods to learn the uncommon meanings of words?* A native English speaker who was unfamiliar with the terminology of waste management would have to find out what a **lift** meant in this context by going to a website or other resource, such as the one @SovereignSun has cited. When occupations and technologies are involved, many common words acquire specialized meanings that might not be found in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In this context:

- A **cell** is an area where the trash is stored within the landfill. Small ones mostly contain only one day's trash and are known as **the daily workface**. Its size is approximately 15.25m long by 15.25m wide by 4.26m high. The amount of trash within the cell is approximately 2,500 tons and is compressed at approximately 1,500 pounds per cubic yard.
- **lifts** are adjoining cells that are arranged in rows and layers.

[**LEARN ABOUT LANDFILLS**](http://www.advanceddisposal.com/for-mother-earth/education-zone/learn-about-landfills.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

***Are there any methods to know the uncommon meanings of the words?***

Start by looking through a comprehensive dictionary. One of my favorites is [OneLook](http://www.wordnik.com/words/lift), which actually lists definitions from a few different dictionaries. It’s easy to navigate and isn’t too encumbered by ad clutter.

In this case, the word *lift* is a very flexible word with a host of meanings. It’s obvious that *lift* is being used a noun in your example, so I scroll through the noun definitions until I see the one which I believe is the meaning in your sentence:

[image]

I could do the same thing for [*cell*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/cell), too, but I’ll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Unfortunately J.R. it's not always that you can find the proper definition by simply looking it up in a dictionary.

Comment: @SovereignSun - Of course not. But when answering the general question, I think Wordnik would give a learner a much better chance than a learner's dictionary which has fewer meanings. Not all dictionaries are created equal. Also worth mentioning is [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/?w=lift&ls=a), which provides links to many specialized dictionaries, such as Avionics, Business, Computing, and more.